# Transfer selected text from input textbox to textarea box?

Tags: javascript

I have no idea how to transfer text from each input textbox to text area line by line in JavaScript. Please help me! I'm beginner to programming and this is my first question :) [image: form design click here]

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp read on this and hope this helps!

Comment: Rather than a picture of your form, it would be better to [edit] your question to include the relevant html.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the full answer, but this is pretty close, as the first input field is completely working. Now, it's up to you redefine this functions to let you handle an ARRAY of input fields accordingly.

```js
var text1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var area = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
function customFn(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  area.innerHTML = text1.value;
  text1.value = ""
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", customFn);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
  <button id="btn">transfer text</button>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
 
</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and waiting for full program :)

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in your answer. You can easily include a [runnable snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Thank you @nnnnnn, I didn't know about this possibility.